# Validation.EncodingRequired CWE 116 by appscan

Tags: web-applications, java, encoding, automated-tests

I am getting Validation.EncodingRequired for this code

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  FileUploadForm uploadForm = (FileUploadForm) form;
  FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
  FormFile formFile = null;
  try {
  formFile = uploadForm.getFile();
  String path = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/"+
  formFile.getFileName();
  outputStream = new 
FileOutputStream(new File(path));
  
outputStream.write(formFile.getFileData());
  } 
  finally {
  if (outputStream != null) {
      outputStream.close();
  }
  }
uploadForm.setMessage("The file 
"+formFile.getFileName()+" is uploaded 
successfully.");
return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
}
```

Can someone suggest to solve issue

```
outputStream.write(formFile.getFileData())
```

Comment: It looks like this code allows the user to upload content, then this content is reflected back to the client.  If that's the case, then the output must be sanitized before being sent back to the client, otherwise this is vulnerable to various types of XSS attacks.  See https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/116.html and https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/ for more info.

Comment: If possible can you please suggest replacement for the same

Comment: Is escaping Only HTML solves the issue?

Comment: It's an iterative process.  Make sure the output is sanitized (by escaping HTML symbols in the output, as per the SO post above).  Then, run your vulnerability scanner again, to see if it finds anything else.  You need to repeat this process, until the scanner finds no issues.

Comment: Ok will try to do that , do i face any issues in the xl file formatting?

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to StackOverflow, where it likely can be better answered.

Comment: Ok i appreciate for this